# How to Perform a Javascript function using Primefaces wizard onnext attribute?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, widget

I am using PrimeFaces 5.3 and eventually want to use the onnext attribute of the wizard to hide the Next button using hideNextNav(). However, I am currently just trying to test this functionality by calling the next() method instead. Since I am new to primefaces and jsf in general, I have attempted using various syntax, but all my attempts have rendered the Next button non-functional. When I try alert() instead, it works correctly, showing a message box and proceeding to the next tab.

My error:

[image: jsf error]

My xhtml code:

```
<script>
    function nextf(){
        PF('wizard').next();
    }
</script>
...
<p:wizard widgetVar="wizard" flowListener="#{editController.onFlowProcess}" onnext="nextf();">
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `next()` call will trigger `onnext` event. What exactly do you want? Why are you calling `next()` once more while `next()` is already being called? (and thus you're basically calling `next()` in an infinite loop, as evident by the error message and stack trace).

Comment: lol you may have discovered the issue. Testing

Comment: Go ahead and leave an answer, and I will mark it! I previously had other issues, but didn't understand the call order. Everything works as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening the next tab triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. The `onnext` event function in turn triggers `PF('wizard').next()` call. The `PF('wizard').next()` in turn triggers the `onnext` event. Etcetera.

And then maximum call stack size was exceeded.

You'd better not call `PF('wizard').next()` during the `onnext` event.

Comment: Hahaha... sure you did nos miss one?

Comment: I believe I understood your post. Maybe one more example just to be sure :P